# Omission Problem in Query Salesforce

Tags: apex, soql

When I execute this query

```
List<AggregateResult> query = [
    SELECT Max(Id) Id, AccountId, Max(CustomField__c) 
    FROM Asset WHERE Status = 'X' 
    AND (CustomField__c = 'Z' 
    OR CustomField__c = 'Y') 
    GROUP BY AccountId LIMIT 1000
];
```

The first time, happen an error:

```
Internal Salesforce.com Error
```

But the second time, I executed this query, the result with success

[image]

Why does this happen?

Edit 1:

Today, I executed this query in the organizer query plugin, and, first time, this was the result:

[image]

in the second time, this was the result:

[image]

Comment: In which context do you execute your query ?

Comment: this query execute in a schedule job...

Comment: This can be because of CPU time limit exceed , query limit etc. Try to check if you are not hitting any specific limits before this query.

Comment: thank you for your answers, this query is the first thing my job executes, so, I am not hitting any specific limits before this query

Comment: Are the sharing settings correctly config-ed for your usage/ user? Uncaught permission issues tend to sometimes produce this internal error.

Comment: this looks like a tablescan query so you may be hitting limits; add some indexed fields (like created/lastmodifiedDate) to see if you get more consistent results

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: if i put this query inside a batch apex, can this works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using 3 techniques

**1 - Query inside loop**: I followed this question: [Query Causes Salesforce Internal Error](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000091y6IAA) because after my query I had a for loop, so I put my query inside this loop, according to the documentation of the Salesforce [Working with Very Large SOQL Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_VLSQ.htm):

> Your SOQL query sometimes returns so many sObjects that the limit on
> heap size is exceeded and an error occurs. To resolve, use a SOQL
> query for loop instead, since it can process multiple batches of
> records by using internal calls to query and queryMore.

The implementation was like this:

```
for (AggregateResult ar : [SELECT Max(Id) Id, AccountId, 
                           Max(CustomField__c) 
                           FROM Asset WHERE Status = 'X' 
                           AND (CustomField__c = 'Z' 
                           OR CustomField__c = 'Y') 
                           GROUP BY AccountId LIMIT 1000])  {  
    //logic here
}
```

unfortunately only this change did not work and the error persisted, well, the first time I execute my query happens an error, but the second time this query, the result with success, so o implemented a second technique:

**2 - Self Test**: I writed a test class that only executes this large query, I scheduled the test class to run 5 minutes before my automation run, I did following this documentation: [Scheduling Run All Apex Tests and emailing results](https://www.forcetree.com/2019/12/scheduling-run-all-apex-tests-and.html)

The implementation was like this:

```
global class SelfTestSchedulable implements Schedulable {

    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx){
        List<ApexClass> testClasses = [SELECT Id FROM ApexClass WHERE Name = 'TestMyLargeQuery'];
        
        List<ApexTestQueueItem> queueItems = new List<ApexTestQueueItem>();

        for (ApexClass testClass : testClasses) {           
            queueItems.add(new ApexTestQueueItem(ApexClassId=testClass.Id)); 
        }        

        insert queueItems;
    }
}
```

unfortunately only this change did not work and the error persisted, so implemented a third technique:

**3 - Moved the query to inside of the Batch class**: Contextualizing, my query stayed inside of the Job, the job pass the results of the query via constructor to the batch because the Batch classes do not support Aggregate in the function `Database.getQueryLocator` see this documentation: [Batch Apex error 'Aggregate query does not support queryMore'](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000333422&type=1), so I chose to put the query in the job, but I had an insight of putting my query inside of the Batch.

The implementation was like this:

```
public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) { 
    List<Id> assetIds = new List<Id>();
    for (AggregateResult ar : [SELECT Max(Id) Id, AccountId, 
                                Max(CustomField__c) 
                                FROM Asset WHERE Status = 'X' 
                                AND (CustomField__c = 'Z' 
                                OR CustomField__c = 'Y') 
                                GROUP BY AccountId LIMIT 1000])  {  
        Id id = (Id)ar.get('Id'); 
        assetIds.add(id); 
    }
    return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT Id, AccountId FROM Asset WHERE Id in :assets '+assetIds);
}
```

And my problem was solved.